# Given a continuous graph. Find the number of intersections by a line segment in log(n)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

Given an array, example : Arr[1 3 4 4 7 8 6 8 6 4 2], where 10^10>Arr[i]>0,  which represents y co-ordinate. x co-ordinate is their corresponding Array index. A continuous graph is formed by joining (i,Arr[i]) and (i+1,Arr[i+1), and so on. So basically it is a graph formed by joining straight lines. Given a line segment parallel to y-axis from x-range (x1 to x2). If given line segment passes through an intersection point, then we count that as 2 intersections except when the left endpoint of intersecting line is (x2,y) or its right endpoint is (x1,y), then we count that as 1 intersection only. Can we find the number of intersections by this line segment log(n) time ?

Answer (score -1):

This is from an ongoing contest. Wait one more day for the editorials.